# C++ COM server memory usage increases over time - analisys with WinDBG

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com, windbg

I am having a problem with an ATL COM server which is using a lot of memory over time. I am suspecting a memory leak but I am not able to pinpoint the cause. The service is adding memory slowly over the course of a 48 hours stress test.

Here is what I gathered in WinDBG by analyzing the process after 1 hour. I am placing here some the objects that occupy most of the memory.

```
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
190        6c3      - a90b0  (32.86)
30         1507     - 3f150  (12.26)

!heap -flt s 190

!heap -p -a 0000000002ae0ee0
address 0000000002ae0ee0 found in
_HEAP @ 1a40000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    0000000002ae0eb0 001c 0000  [00]   0000000002ae0ee0    00190 - (busy)
      combase!CStdIdentity::`vftable'
    7ffd1aa71be7 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x000000000006fb17
    7ffd18676158 combase!CIDObject::GetOrCreateStdID+0x0000000000000128
    7ffd1867a788 combase!CDestObjectWrapper::MarshalInterface+0x00000000000006ca
    7ffd186795c2 combase!CoMarshalInterface+0x00000000000001a2
    7ffd1868145f combase!MarshalHelperMulti+0x000000000000006f
    7ffd1868139f combase!GetInstanceHelperMulti+0x0000000000000083
    7ffd18681129 combase!CObjServer::CreateInstance+0x0000000000000467
    7ffd18b02385 RPCRT4!Invoke+0x0000000000000065
    7ffd18b0ae16 RPCRT4!NdrStubCall2+0x000000000000038b
    7ffd18b170eb RPCRT4!NdrStubCall3+0x000000000000014a
    7ffd187a05ff combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x0000000000000067
    7ffd187a04d9 combase!SyncStubInvoke+0x0000000000000306
    7ffd18633fc9 combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+0x0000000000000279
    7ffd187a13ff combase!AppInvoke+0x000000000000018f
    7ffd187a0e9b combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x0000000000000661
    7ffd187a184e combase!ThreadInvoke+0x0000000000000481
    7ffd18b02614 RPCRT4!DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf+0x0000000000000014
    7ffd18b02517 RPCRT4!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker+0x0000000000000177
    7ffd18b16ebf RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest+0x0000000000000531
    7ffd18b02cc1 RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000201
    7ffd18b02a97 RPCRT4!LRPC_SASSOCIATION::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000237
    7ffd18b01d04 RPCRT4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO+0x000000000000036d
    7ffd18b01afe RPCRT4!LrpcIoComplete+0x00000000000000ae
    7ffd1a9fd394 ntdll!TppAlpcpExecuteCallback+0x0000000000000204
    7ffd1a9fb96d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x00000000000003ad
    7ffd184f15bd KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x000000000000000d
    7ffd1aa343d1 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x000000000000001d

!heap -flt s 30
!heap -p -a 0000000002af5960
address 0000000002af5960 found in
_HEAP @ 1a40000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    0000000002af5930 0006 0000  [00]   0000000002af5960    00030 - (busy)
    7ffd1aa71be7 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x000000000006fb17
    7ffd1a9e0056 ntdll!RtlpAddDebugInfoToCriticalSection+0x0000000000000012
    7ffd1aa79db4 ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount+0x0000000000055dd4
    7ffd18674b24 combase!CStdIdentity::CStdIdentity+0x00000000000002d4
    7ffd1867618d combase!CIDObject::GetOrCreateStdID+0x000000000000015d
    7ffd1867a788 combase!CDestObjectWrapper::MarshalInterface+0x00000000000006ca
    7ffd186795c2 combase!CoMarshalInterface+0x00000000000001a2
    7ffd1868145f combase!MarshalHelperMulti+0x000000000000006f
    7ffd1868139f combase!GetInstanceHelperMulti+0x0000000000000083
    7ffd18681129 combase!CObjServer::CreateInstance+0x0000000000000467
    7ffd18b02385 RPCRT4!Invoke+0x0000000000000065
    7ffd18b0ae16 RPCRT4!NdrStubCall2+0x000000000000038b
    7ffd18b170eb RPCRT4!NdrStubCall3+0x000000000000014a
    7ffd187a05ff combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x0000000000000067
    7ffd187a04d9 combase!SyncStubInvoke+0x0000000000000306
    7ffd18633fc9 combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+0x0000000000000279
    7ffd187a13ff combase!AppInvoke+0x000000000000018f
    7ffd187a0e9b combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x0000000000000661
    7ffd187a184e combase!ThreadInvoke+0x0000000000000481
    7ffd18b02614 RPCRT4!DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf+0x0000000000000014
    7ffd18b02517 RPCRT4!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker+0x0000000000000177
    7ffd18b16ebf RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest+0x0000000000000531
    7ffd18b02cc1 RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000201
    7ffd18b02a97 RPCRT4!LRPC_SASSOCIATION::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000237
    7ffd18b01d04 RPCRT4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO+0x000000000000036d
    7ffd18b01afe RPCRT4!LrpcIoComplete+0x00000000000000ae
    7ffd1a9fd394 ntdll!TppAlpcpExecuteCallback+0x0000000000000204
    7ffd1a9fb96d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x00000000000003ad
    7ffd184f15bd KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x000000000000000d
    7ffd1aa343d1 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x000000000000001d
```

Other objects:

```
size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
48        6c2       - 1e690  (91.91)
1000        1       - 1000   (3.02)

!heap -flt s 48
!heap -p -a 0000000002ab8000
address 0000000002ab8000 found in
_HEAP @ 1a40000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    0000000002ab7fd0 0007 0000  [00]   0000000002ab8000    00048 - (busy)
      combase!g_ForwardingVtbl
    7ffd1aa71be7 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x000000000006fb17
    7ffd18674115 combase!CreateStubFromTypeInfo+0x0000000000000061
    7ffd18b58f63 RPCRT4!CreateStubFromTypeInfo+0x0000000000000043
    7ffd1908dcf8 OLEAUT32!CUnivStubWrapper::Invoke+0x0000000000000098
    7ffd187a04d9 combase!SyncStubInvoke+0x0000000000000306
    7ffd18633fc9 combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+0x0000000000000279
    7ffd187a13ff combase!AppInvoke+0x000000000000018f
    7ffd187a0e9b combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x0000000000000661
    7ffd187a184e combase!ThreadInvoke+0x0000000000000481
    7ffd18b02614 RPCRT4!DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf+0x0000000000000014
    7ffd18b02517 RPCRT4!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker+0x0000000000000177
    7ffd18b16ebf RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest+0x0000000000000531
    7ffd18b02cc1 RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000201
    7ffd18b02a97 RPCRT4!LRPC_SASSOCIATION::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000237
    7ffd18b01d04 RPCRT4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO+0x000000000000036d
    7ffd18b01afe RPCRT4!LrpcIoComplete+0x00000000000000ae
    7ffd1a9fd394 ntdll!TppAlpcpExecuteCallback+0x0000000000000204
    7ffd1a9fb96d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x00000000000003ad
    7ffd184f15bd KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x000000000000000d
    7ffd1aa343d1 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x000000000000001d

!heap -p -a 000000000282f280
address 000000000282f280 found in
_HEAP @ 20a0000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    000000000282f250 0007 0000  [00]   000000000282f280    00048 - (busy)
      ccprovsp!ATL::CComObject<MyCOM>::`vftable'
    7ffd1aa71be7 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x000000000006fb17
    140028c87 ccprovsp!malloc+0x0000000000000067
    14002815e ccprovsp!operator new+0x000000000000000e
    14000280b ccprovsp!ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<MyCOM> >::CreateInstance+0x000000000000005b
    14000239c ccprovsp!ATL::CComCreator2<ATL::CComCreator<ATL::CComObject<MyCOM> >,ATL::CComFailCreator<-2147221232> >::CreateInstance+0x000000000000002c
    1400085a7 ccprovsp!ATL::CComClassFactory::CreateInstance+0x0000000000000077
    7ffd1868134c combase!GetInstanceHelperMulti+0x0000000000000034
    7ffd18681129 combase!CObjServer::CreateInstance+0x0000000000000467
    7ffd18b02385 RPCRT4!Invoke+0x0000000000000065
    7ffd18b0ae16 RPCRT4!NdrStubCall2+0x000000000000038b
    7ffd18b170eb RPCRT4!NdrStubCall3+0x000000000000014a
    7ffd187a05ff combase!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke+0x0000000000000067
    7ffd187a04d9 combase!SyncStubInvoke+0x0000000000000306
    7ffd18633fc9 combase!CCtxComChnl::ContextInvoke+0x0000000000000279
    7ffd187a13ff combase!AppInvoke+0x000000000000018f
    7ffd187a0e9b combase!ComInvokeWithLockAndIPID+0x0000000000000661
    7ffd187a184e combase!ThreadInvoke+0x0000000000000481
    7ffd18b02614 RPCRT4!DispatchToStubInCNoAvrf+0x0000000000000014
    7ffd18b02517 RPCRT4!RPC_INTERFACE::DispatchToStubWorker+0x0000000000000177
    7ffd18b16ebf RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::DispatchRequest+0x0000000000000531
    7ffd18b02cc1 RPCRT4!LRPC_SCALL::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000201
    7ffd18b02a97 RPCRT4!LRPC_SASSOCIATION::HandleRequest+0x0000000000000237
    7ffd18b01d04 RPCRT4!LRPC_ADDRESS::ProcessIO+0x000000000000036d
    7ffd18b01afe RPCRT4!LrpcIoComplete+0x00000000000000ae
    7ffd1a9fd394 ntdll!TppAlpcpExecuteCallback+0x0000000000000204
    7ffd1a9fb96d ntdll!TppWorkerThread+0x00000000000003ad
    7ffd184f15bd KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x000000000000000d
    7ffd1aa343d1 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x000000000000001d
```

Any hint on what should I do next?

Comment: Object life cycle management in COM is based on reference counting. It's really hard  to tell what caused the leak based on the call stack. Try debugdiag instead of Windbg

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems that you have set up GFlags correctly to trace memory allocations. That's a good thing and will definitely help locating the issue. However, the objects you posted are meaningless, because we cannot tell whether they should currently be in use or not.

Doing the analysis in WinDbg is quite hard and needs a lot of manual work. Luckily there is [UMDH (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will be helpful in such a scenario.

**How to proceed**

Since you can reproduce the issue in relatively short time (600 kB in 1 hour is ok), do that. Create a scenario where you reach the same state in your application repeatedly and where (in your opinion) all memory should have been freed again. Over one hour, always create a UMDH snapshot when that state is reached. Later, analyze the log files (this approach is called "Mode 2").

UMDH will sort all memory allocations by call stack. If you manage to draw a graph of the allocations over time, e.g. in Excel, you'll probably see one line which is rising. That's potentially the culprit. You can try [HeapProfiler](https://github.com/kg/HeapProfiler) to generate such a graph (I've never used that before since I have my own tool for creating the graph, unfortunately not ready to be released at this time).

When you know the type of object that is getting lost, you know where it is allocated (from the call stack). Then perform a code review and find the place where it should be released. Try to figure out why it is not released (and that's the really hard part).

**Further reading**

The book [Inside Windows Debugging (Amazaon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735662789) by Tarik Soulami covers UMDH in chapter 8.

You may also want to read or listen to some online tutorials, e.g. [Using UMDH to Find a User-Mode Memory Leak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Finding Memory Leaks with UMDH](http://de.slideshare.net/zblair/finding-memory-leaks-with-umdh).